Custom Data Validation Excel Office javascript API
I want to set custom data validation on my specific range. Actually i want to disbable some ranges like (A2:B10). If user anything type in this he will get error you can't edit this cell value.
here is below code of data validation using office javascript but this is for whole number gareater then 0.
 await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      const rankingRange = sheet.getRange("A2:B10");
      rankingRange.dataValidation.clear();
  
      let greaterThanZeroRule = {
        wholeNumber: {
          formula1: 0,
          operator: Excel.DataValidationOperator.greaterThan
        }
      };
      rankingRange.dataValidation.rule = greaterThanZeroRule;
  
      rankingRange.dataValidation.prompt = {
        message: "Please enter a positive number.",
        showPrompt: true,
        title: "Positive numbers only."
      };
  
      rankingRange.dataValidation.errorAlert = {
        message: "Sorry, only positive numbers are allowed",
        showAlert: true,
        style: "Stop",
        title: "Negative Number Entered"
      };
  
      await context.sync();
    });

i want to set data validation on cell range for allow edit false.
